# Toggle a spinner on button click inside an antd table row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd

I have a table like this with a column that contains a button like this:

```
const columns = [
...
  {
    title: "button",
    dataIndex: "key",
    render: (text, record) => {
      return (
        <Button
          icon={<DeleteOutlined />}
          onClick={() => pendingToggle()}
        ></Button>
      );
    }
  }
];
```

When you click on this button it should swap the button with `<Spin />` from ant design only on that row it is clicked. I have written a piece of code but it doesn't work you can find it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-design-forked-q3rhi?file=/index.js) !

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use React states so that the DOM gets re-rendered.
To do so, you need a react component, something like:

```
function ButtonCell() {
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(false);

  return pending ? (
    <Spin />
  ) : (
    <Button icon={<DeleteOutlined />} onClick={() => setPending(true)}>
      Delete
    </Button>
  );
}
```

In your table you can type:

```js
{
  title: "button",
  dataIndex: "key",
  render: () => {
    return <ButtonCell />;
  } // or just `render: ButtonCell`
}
```

Working example:

[image: Edit ant.design (forked)]

Comment: Thanks it works. But going back to my example what if I want to log `name` from button's row through a function, how would I do that? Like when you click on a delete button it logs the `name` associated with that row which can be find in the `data` constant!